# How to find supremum of a certain sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

a is a real sequence $ a: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $a(0) = 0, a(n):= n^\frac{1}{n} $ $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}$.
What's the Supremum of $a(\mathbb{N})$ ?

I've calculated the first derivative of the function $ f(x) = x^\frac{1}{x}$ and determined the critical point. My result is max(a($\mathbb{N}$)) = e.
Can I now treat the maximum equivalent to the supremum or is there an other way ?

Answer (score 1):

While $e$ maximises the value of $f(x)$, $a(n)$ is only defined for $n$ a natural number. But what you have shown is that $a(n)$ increases for $n<e$ and decreases for $n>e$, so the two values of $n$ to investigate are 2 and 3, since $2 < e < 3$.

$a(2) = \sqrt{2}$

$a(3) = \sqrt[3]{3}$

As $(\sqrt[3]{3})^6 = 9$ and $(\sqrt{2})^6 = 8$, $a(3)$ is maximal and the supremum is therefore $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where does the power 6 come from ?

Comment: Power 6 is just a convenient way to get to an answer I can work out without a calculator.  (I have a 1/2 power and a 1/3 power, and 6 is the LCM of 2 and 3), so by seeing a(2)^6 < a(3)^6 I know that a(2)<a(3).